# (1) If $r \gt 1$ show that $r^n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ (2) If $0\lt r\lt1$ show that $r^n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: calculus

I have problems figure in out these question for my advanced calculus class. I couldn't get the answered right. I try using some examples we did in class to help me with the questions but it didnt do much help. If anyone can help me I really will appreciated it. I thank you in advanced.

Comment: What did you try, what are your thoughts on the matter?  (A broad hint for (1): Do you know the _binomial theorem_ at all?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $0<r<1$, then $(r^n)_{n=0}^\infty$ is a decreasing sequence which is bounded below by zero (why?). Then it has a limit by the monotonic theorem. Let $L$ be the limit. Then
$r^{n+1}=rr^n \to rL$ (using the limit laws). But $(r^{n+1})_{n=0}^\infty=(r^{n})_{n=1}^\infty$ and so converges to $L$ since finite terms does not affect the limit. Then $rL=L$, i.e., $(r-1) \cdot L=0$ and since $r\not=1$, then $L=0$ as desired.

Now suppose that $r>1$ and for sake of contradiction suppose that $r^n\to c$. Since $1/r<1$ for what we have shown  $(1/r)^n \to 0$. Then $(1/r)^nr^n\to c\cdot 0=0$. But $(1/r)^nr^n= (r/r)^n=1 \to 1$, since the limit is unique then this would imply $0=1$, a contradiction.